# Why can't my bash script export variables?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am using MSYS and have a file vars.txt with variable, value keys like:

```
WINDIR C:/WINDOWS
STS_BUILD_DIRECTORY D:/STS/TMP
ALLUSERSPROFILE C:/Documents and Settings/All Users
```

I want to read this in and set environment variables up. I have a bash script setenv:

```
while read var value;
do
  echo "performing export $var=$value"
  export $var='$value'
done
```

and I call it with

```
cat vars.txt | source setenv
```

However in my environment the variables are not set. I also tried making it into a function but no joy.  Anybody here know what I'm doign wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: `setenv` is a poor name for your script, since it's the name of a builtin in several shells.

Comment: @Daenyth Thanks - yeah it felt kind of wrong at the time but bash doesn't seem to have it. mapenv is a better name anyways ;)

Comment: I have also found same issue(vars not set) if I add a pipe after sourcing a script. e.g. 'source setit.sh' vars set ok, 'source setit.sh |tee setit.log' vars are not set. Surprising. Not intuitive. Watch out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pipe sets up a subshell. When the subshell exits, the variables are lost.

Try this:

```
source setenv < vars.txt
```

Also your single quotes may prevent the expansion of the variable (I don't know if this is true in MSYS). Try changing the `export` line to this:

```
export $var="$value"
```

You can use `declare` instead of `export` if the variables don't need to be exported.

Comment: So I have to use temp files? (vars.txt was just for testing) I have a function that generates vars.txt. It works OK with: generate_envmap > /tmp/envmap.txt; apply_env < /tmp/envmap.txt. Would be nicer to do generate_envmap | apply_env.

Comment: @danio: I just based my answer on your example. You said you "have a file". I didn't know that you didn't already have the file. You can use process substitution in Bash: `source apply_env < <(generate_envmap)`

Comment: Thanks that seems to be what I want but the MSYS version of bash doesn't seem to have implemented process substitution :-(

Comment: @danio: Try using a here string and command substitution: `source apply_env <<< $(generate_envmap)`

Comment: Thanks for that but doesn't seem to do anything. No errors, but no effect either. The temp file solution is a little ugly but fine.